# how to .define() a color with stylus

Tags: node.js, stylus

I try to define a color using stylus API .define(name, value):

```
var stylus = require('stylus');
stylus('.foo { color: darken(mycolor, 50%) }')
.define('mycolor', '#123')
.render(function(err, css) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(css);
});
```

error:

```
TypeError: expected rgba or hsla, but got string:'#123'
```

In the [documentation](https://github.com/stylus/stylus/blob/master/docs/js.md#definename-node), I cannot see any reference to a *color* type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.define('mycolor', '#123')` always defines a string, as you may have found out. Even if you say `.define('mycolor', 'rgba(0,0,0,0)')`, you will get the same error.

What you need to do is define a `rgba` or `hsla` node, which you can do like so:

```
stylus('.foo { color: darken(mycolor, 50%) }')
.define('mycolor', new stylus.nodes.RGBA(1, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33))
```

Sadly, I've been unable to find an easy way to define a colour node from a colour string directly.

`new stylus.Parser('#123').lexer.color().val`, or `new stylus.Parser('#123').peek().val` will work for hex strings, though.

Comment: nice, but I just wondering if there is a way (public API) to invoke the rule/value parser for my color string ?

Comment: then:  
.define('mycolor', new stylus.Parser('#123').peek().val)